# Is Interop.Domino dll thread safe?

Tags: c#-2.0, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am using Interop.Domino dll version 1.2 in c# application, and using multithreading to access multiple NSF file at same time by creating new session for each thread created (Max 5 threads at a time).

For the large NSF files, I was getting the Notes error like memory segment overflow.
 To overcome this problem, i used Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object) to release the necessary Notesdocument, and NotesView object where ever possible.

Now, the issues is like, i am able to access 2 NSF files but the rest threads are going in dll exceptions as few Notes object are getting null.

Kindly provide me some help....

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I have been doing some experiments on this very same question recently.

I have written a test program that launches two different types of threads.  Each thread is configured to work with 8 to 10 users.  Every thread does have to read the Domino Directory in order to locate the mail file for the users, and each thread also writes results documents to a single common NSF file. But for the main work in the mail files, no two threads are ever accessing the same NSF.  The NSF files are spread across two servers.  Five of the threads are using NotesDatabase.Search, and five of the threads are reading a NotesView and drilling down to the NotesViewEntry objects.  I ran into the same memory issue that you encountered, and solved it the same way -- but I was very careful not to release the Database objects for the Domino Directory or the output NSF.  I've run this test code with up to 10 active threads, with no problems.

This is encouraging, however I do not think this is really enough proof that the Domino COM objects are completely thread safe.