# connecting to a NotesSession in C# via Multi Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, lotus-domino

I am trying to connect to a Domino Session which works fine when testing in isolation, however as soon as I put it in a thread I run into problems.

This works fine when I put in a Unit test, so I know I can connect to the server fine.

```
NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
string  DominoPassword = Helpers.GetConfigSetting("DominoPassword");
session.Initialize(DominoPassword);
```

However when I put this in a thread (want to be able to connect to Domino several times)  I
get the following error
"{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}"

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago I definitely got farther than this with testing of multi-threaded Domino Interop in C#. I don't recall seeing that error.  It might be due to a difference between our respective dev/test environments. It's long enough ago, though, that I don't recall what my environments were when I ran my tests.

But whether or not the Domino objects are thread-safe remains an open question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824371/is-interop-domino-dll-thread-safe).  As far as I know, IBM has never said that they are. (Also, last time I checked, IBM said that the classes are not supported on Win64 platforms even in Win32 applications, so that might be entering into your problem.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the reply, I saw your original comment in Stack Overflow, not sure its the 32/64 problem as I can get the connection to work when I take it out of the threading.  Do you have the code you used to get the threading to work?  Just wanted to check its the same I have. Thanks

Comment: I'm nor sure.  I'll have to look for it. It was probably on a dev VM, which probably still exists, but I'll have to find it.

Comment: I did find the code. I can post it somewhere for you if you want, but the key difference does stand out. I initialized the NotesSession in main, used it to retrieve a document, and dispatched the document to a thread. I did not try to initialize a new NotesSession per thread. If I needed anything above the level of the NotesDocument that was passed into the thread, I used doc.parent to get the NotesDatabase, and db.parent to get the NotesSession. I designed my code to assure that threads would not be working in the same database, view, etc.

Comment: Yes thanks for this, I just did the same and it worked.  Thanks for coming back to me!